# Azure Pipeline: Make Jobs run on the same Agent from the same pool

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a YAML script that looks something like this:

```yaml
jobs:
- job: UnixBuild
  pool: 
    name: BuildMachinesUnix
  steps:
  - bash: echo "Build Unix"

- job: WinBuild
  pool: 
    name: BuildMachinesWindows
  steps:
  - bash: echo "Build Windows"

- job: UnixRelease
  dependsOn:
    - UnixBuild
    - WinBuild
  condition: and(succeeded('UnixBuild'), succeeded('WinBuild'))
  pool: 
    name: BuildMachinesUnix
  steps:
  - bash: echo "Release on Unix"

- job: WinRelease
  dependsOn:
    - UnixBuild
    - WinBuild
  condition: and(succeeded('UnixBuild'), succeeded('WinBuild'))
  pool: 
    name: BuildMachinesWindows
  steps:
  - bash: echo "Release on Windows"
```

Each Pool has several agent, and I want the Agent that took on the UnixBuild job to also handle the UnixRelease job, as all the files for that release is there, so that I don't needto rebuild it, in the release step, and the same goes from the WindowsBuild

Is such a thing possible, if so how?

If not, have any good suggestion for how to only release if both Unix and Windows succedes, without having to compile it twice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want the Agent that took on the UnixBuild job to also handle the UnixRelease job, as all the files for that release is there, so that I don't needto rebuild it, in the release step, and the same goes from the WindowsBuild

The answer is yes.

To resolve this issue, we could get the agent name from the `UnixBuild` job， then pass this as `demands`:

```
  - job: UnixBuild
    pool: 
      name: BuildMachinesUnix
    steps:
    - bash: echo "$(Agent.Name)"
    - bash: |
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=someName;isOutput=true;]$(Agent.Name)"
      name: setVariable

  - job: UnixRelease
    dependsOn:
      - UnixBuild
      - WinBuild
    condition: and(succeeded('UnixBuild'), succeeded('WinBuild'))
    variables: 
      TestsomeName: $[ dependencies.UnixBuild.outputs['setVariable.someName'] ]
    pool: 
      name: BuildMachinesUnix
      demands:
      - Agent.Name -equals $(TestsomeName)
    steps:
    - bash: echo "$(TestsomeName)"
```

Comment: This is possible but leads to queuing issues, because your second job is queued last if something gets in between. This means that if you want to save time by having better caching this will bite you.

Comment: Also, if you're trying to not download the same files over and over again, but another job wipes out the files cache on the agent before the second job runs, then you've got a broken build.