# How to create Azure Pipeline Template to run a jobList all on the same agent?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to make a pipeline template that takes a JobList a parameter and runs all the jobs, while ensuring that they run on the same agent every time.  Basically the approach I've been taking is to try to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71642941/11301846) into a genericized template format.

This is what I have so far, and I've tried a lot of slight tweaks of this with nothing passing the Validate test on the pipeline that calls it.

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: jobsToRun
    type: jobList
  - name: pool
    type: string
    default: Default
  - name: demands
    type: object
    default: []

jobs:
  - job:
    steps: 
      - script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=agentName;isOutput=true;]$(Agent.Name)" 
    pool:
      name: ${{ parameters.pool }}
      demands:
      - ${{ each demand in parameters.demands }}:
          ${{ demand }}
  - ${{ each j in parameters.jobsToRun }}:
      ${{ each pair in j }}:
        ${{ pair.key }} : ${{ pair.value }}
      pool:
        name: Default
        demands:
        - Agent.Name -equals $(agentName)
```

What am I doing wrong here? It seems like it should be possible if that answer I reference is correct, but it seems like I'm just a bit off.

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Answer (score 1):

Name missing on the job.., example below.

```
- job: 'test-Name'
```

Steps need a associated job and pool to run is declared inside

```
 jobsToRun:
        - job: sample_job1
          displayName: "sample_job1"
          pool:
            name: "your_PoolName"
          steps:
            - script: |
                  echo "Hi"
```

On this bottom pool declaration...

```
 pool:
        name: Default
        demands:
        - Agent.Name -equals $(agentName)
```

i am not sure but i have tried this many times but i  think this can't be included separate to the job since each individual job is passed as parameter. pool definition needs to be inside the job or inside the job template if you are using templates..

example:

```
jobsToRun:
            - job: output_message_job1
              displayName: "in pipe Output Message Job"
              pool:
                name: "your_PoolName"
              steps:
                - script: |
                      echo "Hi"
```